# JS says an object is undefined even though it shows with console.log

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, console.log, prisma

As the title states, my JS says an object is undefined even though if I console.log the parent it shows. I'm using prisma, but all that does is return a list of the objects containing `{id, title, user:{id, name}}`.
Code:

```
const userProjects = await prisma.projectMembers.findMany({
  where: {
    userId: token._id
  },
  select: {
    project: {
      select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        user: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
userProjects.map(project => {
  console.log(project)
  console.log(project.user)
  return {
    id: project.id,
    title: project.title,
    user: project.user.id,
  }
})
```

Output:

[image: Console.log output]

Comment: It should be `project.project.user`. Don't you see the nested `project` property in the output of `console.log(project)`?

Comment: @Barmar Seems like an answer to me. Answer box is that way: ↓

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the screenshot, there's a nested `project` property, and the `user` property is inside that. So `project.user` should be `project.project.user`.

```
userProjects.map(project => {
  console.log(project)
  console.log(project.project.user)
  return project.project;
})
```

There's no need for you to create your own object when returning, since it's the same as `project.project`.